Inject a list of Implementations using Custom annotation in Dropwizard
I am trying to have different implementation of an Interface and group them into categories.
something like this
Custom Qualifiers
But I always get HK2 failure as it is not able to satisfy the dependencies
There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=List<TestCase>,parent=TestCaseManager,qualifiers={},position=0,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1864550692)

This is what i have done so far and i am not able to figure out what the issue is
public interface TestCase {
    public void run(int id);
}

Created custom annotations
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface CommonTests {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface DbTests {
}

Added implementations and annotate
@CommonTests
public class CommonTestCaseOne implements TestCase {
    private final TestService testService;
    @Inject
    public CommonTestCaseOne(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(int propertyId) {
        System.out.println("CommonTestCaseOne "+testService.getTestResult());
    }
}

@DbTests
public class DBTestCaseOne implements TestCase {

    private final TestService testService;

    @Inject
    public DBTestCaseOne(TestService testService) {
        this.testService = testService;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(int propertyId) {
        System.out.println("DBTestCaseOne "+testService.getTestResult());
    }
}

Trying to wire these using Manager class.
package tester.testcases;

import tester.testcases.common.CommonTests;
import tester.testcases.db.DbTests;

public class TestCaseManager {

    private final List<TestCase> dbTestcases;

    private final List<TestCase> commonTestcases;

    public List<TestCase> getDbTestcases(){
        return this.dbTestcases;
    }

    public List<TestCase> getCommonTestcases(){
        return this.commonTestcases;
    }
    @Inject
    public TestCaseManager(@DbTests List<TestCase> dbTestCases, @CommonTests List<TestCase> commonTestCases) {
        this.dbTestcases = dbTestCases;
        this.commonTestcases = commonTestCases;
    }

}

Inject these into my service
public class HelloWorldService {

    private final TestCaseManager testCaseManager;

    @Inject
    public HelloWorldService(TestCaseManager testCaseManager) {
        this.testCaseManager = testCaseManager;
    }

    public void runAllTests(){
        List<TestCase> dbTests = this.testCaseManager.getDbTestcases();
        for (TestCase tc : dbTests){
            tc.run(1);
        }
        List<TestCase> commonTests = this.testCaseManager.getCommonTestcases();
        for (TestCase tc : commonTests){
            tc.run(1);
        }
    }
}

And finally trying to use it in my resource
@Singleton
@Path("/hello-world")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloWorldResource {

    private final HelloWorldService testCaseService;

    @Inject
    public HelloWorldResource(HelloWorldService testCaseService){
        this.testCaseService = testCaseService;
    }
    @GET
    @Timed
    public void runTests() {
        testCaseService.runAllTests();

    }
}

And my application configuration looks like this
@Override
    public void run(final testConfiguration configuration,
                    final Environment environment) {
        environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {

                bindAsContract(TestService.class).in(Singleton.class);
                bindAsContract(DBTestCaseOne.class).in(Singleton.class);
                bindAsContract(DBTestCaseTwo.class).in(Singleton.class);
                bindAsContract(CommonTestCaseOne.class).in(Singleton.class);
                bindAsContract(CommonTestCaseTwo.class).in(Singleton.class);

                bindAsContract(TestCaseManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
                bindAsContract(HelloWorldService.class).in(Singleton.class);
            }
        });
        environment.jersey().register(HelloWorldResource.class);
    }


Could any one please point me in the right direction. I am kind of lost at this point.
I expected that this will autowire the implementations into the list and later I will be able to access these instance and run the methods.
@DbTests List<TestCase> dbTestCases, 
@CommonTests List<TestCase> commonTestCases

But it is not resolving the dependencies and not able to inject it
